# MySQL RAND() Without Repeating a Value in a Specific Column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to Select a random set of results (5 results) from a table without selecting two notes from the same user and ordering those results based on date added and having the record added within 30 days.  For example, let's say my table has the following columns:

```
user_notes
  -note_id
  -user_id
  -note
  -note_added
```

I'm pretty close with

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM user_notes
    WHERE note_added > date_sub(note_added,interval 30 day)
    GROUP BY user_id
    ORDER BY RAND()
) user_notes
ORDER BY note_added DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

I feel like the group by statement is screwing things up and while a user may have a record added within the last 30 days I'm just getting the first record they create due to the group by.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not test it but for me it looks fine except the `date_sub()`: Shouldn't it be

```
date_sub(now(),interval 30 day)?
```

Comment: duh! That was it.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM user_notes
    WHERE note_added > date_sub(note_added,interval 30 day)
    ORDER BY RAND()
) user_notes
    GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY note_added DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

Try this and take a look at the answer from sw0x2A

Answer (score 0):

Whether you want the random records for a specific user or not? if yes means, you can add one more condition to where clause like Specific user_id. Try it....

Comment: The question was to do exactly the opposite of that.